# Starting and Stopping Services with Puppet

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-services, puppet

I want to stop a service, execute a Powershell script and then start the service again using Puppet. The code below does not work because `My Service` is defined twice.

```
service { 'My Service':
    ensure  => 'stopped',
    require => Package['Install Go Agent']
}
exec { 'Do Stuff':
    command   => '...',
    provider  => powershell,
    require   => Service['Go Agent']
}
service { 'My Service':
    ensure  => 'started',
    require => Exec['Install Go Agent']
}
```

In essence my Powershell script is setting the windows service username and password which sadly, you cannot do using Puppet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Puppet is Not Procedural

First of all, you are thinking about this in a procedural manner. Puppet is not a procedural language. It defines your end state. You want to instead define when the exec should run idempotently and have the service subscribe to it.

#### How To

This is similar to package/file/service, where you would refresh (restart) the service when a file changes. A good read is at https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_relationships.html and http://www.puppetcookbook.com/posts/restart-a-service-when-a-file-changes.html.

```
package { 'My Package':
    ensure   => latest,
}

exec { 'Do Stuff':
    command   => '...',
    #onlyif/unless => '...', #make it idempotent
    #refreshonly => true #make it idempotent
    provider  => powershell,
    require   => Package['My Package']
}

service { 'My Service':
    ensure  => 'started',
    require => Exec['Do Stuff']
}
```

You definitely need to ensure that the PowerShell doesn't run every time, [only if it is refreshed](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/type.html#exec-attribute-refreshonly), or through either a check with [onlyif](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/type.html#exec-attribute-onlyif) or [unless](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/type.html#exec-attribute-unless).

#### Windows Specifics

So now the Windows specifics. On Windows, unlike Linux, you can't simply replace and/or update locked files. So that exec would need to detect if the service exists, shut it down, then make updates. In your case you will also probably need it to create the service if it doesn't already exist. You may also be able to get away with updating the credentials without shutting down the service.

#### Puppet Defines Desired State

The one thing the exec doesn't need to do is put the service in a started state. That is always handled by the service resource. The service will detect it is not running and start itself if required. It will also restart itself if `exec['Do Stuf']` runs because of the way the relationship is defined.

### Puppet Future

Now for the stuff you should be watching for with Puppet!

- [PUP-5477 - Windows service provider should be able to create and destroy services](https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-5477)
- [PUP-1289 - Ability to manage a Windows service's user account and password](https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-1289)

You can subscribe, vote and comment on these. It helps us prioritize work when we know what users and customers are having issues with.

Comment: Additionally if you are a Puppet Enterprise customer and really feel those tickets are a top priority for your company, let support know as well.

Comment: I've seen your talks, it great to see you active on StackOverflow. Thanks for the answer.